# In search of algorithm to group similar data

Tags: php, algorithm

A simple question, but an answer that has been tormenting me for days...

I have as input an array (php) of 2 aliases,
let's say:

```
Array(
  Array(1,5),
  Array(6,8),
  Array(6,1),
  Array(9,3),
)
```

Each of those state "1" is the same as "5", "6" is the same as "8",...
Simple, now I need to group those, looking at the example above, the algorithm should give me, if I ask nicely, two groups:

```
Array(1,5,6,8) and Array(9,3)
```

Simple commutation logic, but I cannot find a way of tackling it with code! Any guideline would be much appreciated!!

Comment: it was very interesting to find algorithm for your question, thank you :)

Comment: see my answer below - there is complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this insanely fast using the union-find algorithm.

The idea is to have a forest of trees, where each tree represents elements "that are equal". You represent this tree as a simple array, where a[i] either can be the parent of i, -1 if i is the root, or say -2 if i is not yet in a tree.

In your case you would start with the simple tree:

```
1   
 \  
  5
```

The next thing you want it to join 6 and 8. However, they are both unassigned, so you you add a new tree. (That is a[6]=-1, a[8]=6):

```
1    6   
 \    \  
  5    8
```

Now you want to join 6 and 1. You find out which sets they belong to, by following their parents to the top. Coincidentally they are both roots. In this case we make the smallest tree the child of the other tree. (a[6]=1)

```
  1  
 / \ 
6   5
 \
  8
```

Finally we want to join 9 and 3, they are both unassigned, so we create a new tree. (a[3]=-1, a[9]=3)

```
  1    9
 / \    \
6   5    3
 \
  8
```

Say you also have 5=3? Follow their parents till you reach the roots. You find that they are not already equal, so you merge the trees. Since the 9 controls a less high tree, we add it to one's tree, to get:

```
  .1.
 / | \
6  9  5
 \  \
  8  3
```

As you can see it is now easy to check whether two elements are in the same set. Say you wanna test whether 8 and 3 are equal? Just follow their paths upwards, and you will see that 8 is in the set represented by one, and three in the set represented by 9. Hence they are unequal.

Using the heuristic of always putting the smaller tree under the bigger, gives you an log(n) average find or merge time. The Wikipedia article explains an extra trick, that will make it basically constant time.

Answer (score 1):

I would build some kind of tree from these, and use colorization to separate components.
For example let G=[E,V], E= {1, 5, 6, 7, 9 }, V = { {1,5}, {6,8}, {6,1}, {9,3} } where G is a graph with V vertices and E edges. Now start with a random vertex, than color recursively all of it's neighbour to color C1 (with Breadth-first search). If you can't find new neighbours you got the first group. Now start with a new uncolored vertex and a new color C2. Repeat this until you have no more vertices.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class AliasesFinder
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $chains;
    /** @var array */
    protected $aliases;
    protected $digits;

    public function __construct($aliases)
    {
        $this->aliases = $aliases;

        //collect all digits
        $digits = array();
        foreach ($this->aliases as $alias_pair)
        {
            if (!in_array($alias_pair[0], $digits)) $digits[] = $alias_pair[0];
            if (!in_array($alias_pair[1], $digits)) $digits[] = $alias_pair[1];
        }
        $this->digits = $digits;
    }

    public function find_all_aliases($digit, &$chain = array())
    {
        //if $digit already in some chain - return, don't spend time to count another time
        if (!empty($this->chains))
        {
            foreach ($this->chains as $existing_chain)
            {
                if (in_array($digit, $existing_chain)) return false;
            }
        }

        //$digit is part of chain already
        $chain[] = $digit;

        foreach ($this->aliases as $alias_pair)
        {
            //if alias of digit not in chain yet - add this alias-digit and all aliases of this alias-digit to chain
            if ($digit==$alias_pair[0] && (empty($chain) || !in_array($alias_pair[1], $chain)))
            {
                $this->find_all_aliases($alias_pair[1], $chain);
            }
            elseif ($digit==$alias_pair[1] && (empty($chain) || !in_array($alias_pair[0], $chain)))
            {
                $this->find_all_aliases($alias_pair[0], $chain);
            }
        }
        return $chain;

    }

    public function getChains()
    {
        foreach ($this->digits as $digit)
        {
            $aliases = $this->find_all_aliases($digit);
            if ($aliases!==false) $this->chains[] = $aliases;
        }
        return $this->chains;
    }
}

$aliases = Array(
    Array(1, 5),
    Array(6, 8),
    Array(6, 1),
    Array(9, 3),
);

$finder = new AliasesFinder($aliases);
print_r($finder->getChains());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of a disjoint set union problem.

Wikipedia has a page about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

There are some sample algorithms that solve the problem on the wikipedia page.  Is wikipedia clear enough for you?